# obtain index of a row in Julia dataframe (analogue of iterrows?)

Tags: dataframe, indexing, iteration, julia

Is there any way to obtain the index of a row and the row object while iterating through a df in Julia? If not, even a way to find the index of a row would be great, as I could simply use `eachrow()` and then find the iterated row's index, though I imagine this is less likely considering that naming a df's index isn't really supported in Julia.

For context, I need the index in order to find the first occurrence of 0 in each column of a df so that I can replace it with another value (say, 99). To do this, I want to iterate through all the rows of each column in a df. e.g. for df = DataFrame(a = [1, 0, 2], b = [0, 1, 0], c = [0, 0, 4]) the code:

```
for col_index in ["a", "b", "c"]
    for row in eachrow(select(df, :i))
        if row[1] == 0
            df[row.index, :i] = 99
            break
        end
    end
end
```

would turn df into

```
1 99 99
99 1 0 
2 0 4
```

Sorry if this is a silly question, though I could not find anything to the effect of either of my goals online.

Comment: Not tested, but `enumerate` doesn't work with `eachrow` ?

Comment: I had no idea enumerate worked with julia... Thanks! Saves me from manually writing a counter in, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can use `rownumber` function to get the row number in the data frame from which the `DataFrameRow` was taken.
2. as `DataFrameRow` is mutable you can write your loop just as:

```
for col_index in ["a", "b", "c"]
    for row in eachrow(df)
        if row[col_index] == 0
            row[col_index] = 99
            break
        end
    end
end
```

3. Finally it is faster to do what you want like this:

```
for col_index in ["a", "b", "c"]
    col = df[!, col_index]
    loc = findfirst(==(0), col)
    isnothing(loc) || (col[loc] = 99)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get something which is good enough by using `enumerate(eachrow(df))` h/t @Antonello.

From the toy code I wrote in the question, this looks like:

```
for col_index in ["a", "b", "c"]
    for (row_index, row) in enumerate(eachrow(select(df, :col_index)))
        if row[1] == 0
            df[row_index, :col_index] = 99
            break
        end
    end
end
```